# POST request in fiddler: sending custom object which has another object as a member

Tags: c#, json, api

I need to test an endpoint with fiddler using json requests. I know you can send custom object by adding this to the request body....

```
{
    "Name" : "testing//moretest//tiredd",
    "Description": "this is a test.",
}
```

but this object has a custom "Metadata" object associated that I also want to populate...

```
public class MetadataModel
{
    public int Identifier { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

So obviously, I tried making the request body as follows to no avail...Any help?

```
{
    "Name" : "testing//moretest//tiredd",
    "Description": "this is a test.",
    "Metadata" : {"Identifier" : "2", "Path" : "Test"}
}
```

I have also tried wrapping the braces in quotes...no luck.

If I leave out the "Metadata" line, the object is populated and the Metadata object is null. When I include it, the entire object is null

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
"Name" : "testing//moretest//tiredd",
"Description": "this is a test.",
"Metadata" : {"Identifier" : 2, "Path" : "Test"}
}
```

Assuming Ralph WIllgoss's answer doesn't solve the problem (and it may, I've missed that before), you probably just need to remove the quotes from your 2 - JSON integers shouldn't be quoted, so it won't pick that up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the request headers for json correctly?

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

What did you get in the HTTP response, can you post it?